# why the size of the image is 0 x 0

Tags: java, opencv, opencv3.0

despite the image in the provided path exists on the HD with size = 120*80
when i read it using HighGUI.imread(), the returned image has size 0 * 0

**Code**:

```
public class ROI {

static final String PATH_0 = [omitted]///A full path to an image actually existing on my machine

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);

    Mat imgOriginal = Highgui.imread(PATH_0);// this image is 128*80
    showInFrame(imgOriginal);
    system.out.printlin(imgOriginal.size());// results 0 * 0

}

private static void showInFrame(Mat mat) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    JFrame mediaFrame = new JFrame("Media");
    mediaFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    /*JLabel mediaPanel = new JLabel();
    mediaFrame.setContentPane(mediaPanel);*/

    Highgui.imwrite("c:/private/img.jpg", mat);
    ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("c:/private/img.jpg");
    JLabel label = new JLabel("label", image, JLabel.CENTER);

    mat.release();
    mediaFrame.setSize(300,300);
    mediaFrame.add(label);
    mediaFrame.setVisible(true);
    mediaFrame.validate();
}
```

Comment: what r u doing inside showInFrame()

Answer (score 0):

this is because you are calling .release() on the Mat object.
from the docs: .release() deallocates the matrix if needed.

so i suggest to comment this method out